# .exe parou de funcionar

Tags: c++

Boa noite, escrevi um arquivo em c++ porém não está mais funcionando,o código compila tudo certo, mas se eu colocar pra executar aparece a mensagem de que o programa parou de funcionar, se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato. código abaixo!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

#define K 9.0e09  // constante eletrica no vacuo

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

   int Q1 = atof(argv[1]);
   int Q2 = atof(argv[2]);
   double dist = atof(argv[3]); 
/*

   int Q1, Q2;
   double dist;

   cin >> Q1;
   cin >> Q2;
   cin >> dist;


  //char *OutputFileName=argv[4];
   int Q1 = 1;
   int Q2 = 2;
   double dist = 0.01;
*/

   ofstream Output1("Output.dat");  // valor da força elétrica (em Newtons)

   cout << "Forca eletrica = " << (K*Q1*Q2*pow(10,-12))/pow(dist,2) << endl;

   Output1 << Q1 << " " << Q2 << " " << dist << " " << (K*Q1*Q2*pow(10,-12))/pow(dist,2) << endl;

   return 0;

} //int main
/*-----------------------end of main program--------------------------*/
```

Comment: Como você está chamando o programa? Não está checando `argc`, então possivelmente seja que você não está respeitando a CLI que você definiu

Answer (score 3):

**Igor**,

O @jefferson-quesado comentou sobre checar o `argc` para impedir 'erros estranhos' ao rodar o programa. É fundamental que faça tal checagem se espera algum argumento na chamada do programa. Em seu caso, você terá 4 argumentos: o próprio nome do programa, `Q1`, `Q2` e `dist`.

1. Se invocar/executar o programar sem fornecer os argumentos, ele executa `main()`. Dentro de `main()`, ele executa a atribuição de `Q1` mas interrompe a execução em seguida pois `argv` vai tentar acessar uma área de memória não reservada a ele quando `Q2` for tentar armazenar o valor de `argv`. Surge o erro de falha de segmentação.
2. Se invocar/executar o programar fornecendo os argumentos de forma parcial, ele executa `main()`. Dentro de `main()`, ele interrompe a execução pois `argv` vai tentar acessar uma área de memória não reservada a ele e, apesar de pelo menos `Q1` passar no teste, `Q2` ou `dist` vão tentar armazenar o valor inexistente. Surge o erro de falha de segmentação.

Neste caso, se tivesse checado `argc`, provavelmente teria notado que **esqueceu dos argumentos ao invocar o programa**. Pois **o seu código está OK**, rodando normalmente. A única forma dele fornecer uma falha de segmentação (ou *segmentation fault*) é realmente não fornecendo os argumentos necessários ao executar o seu compilado.

Exemplos com erro:

```
g++ codigo.cpp -o meu_programa
./meu_programa  # sem argumentos
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

g++ codigo.cpp -o meu_programa
./meu_programa 20 # argumentos parciais
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Exemplo correto:

```
g++ codigo.cpp -o meu_programa
./meu_programa 10 20 30 # todos os argumentos
> Forca eletrica = 0.002
```

Você pode usar o [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/B10sSlceE) para verificar que funciona normalmente

---

Note que exemplifiquei como estaria no *Linux* em que uso o *g++* para compilar. No *Windows* pode estar usando alguma *IDE* ou algo do tipo. Mas a ideia central é a mesma: precisa dos argumentos!